# Orange: Group samples by a "splitting" feature for cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation, orange, sampling

I need to split my datasets based on my own feature column in order to hold together certain data rows (e.g. from one patient, or compound) for cross-validation (CV).

In Orange 3.11, Test&Score contains "Cross validation by feature", but it is disabled. The widget documentation contains a screenshot still without it.

Is this a feature that is currently under development? Or do I have to define the relevant column differently to enable the option? (It's "meta" right now.) Or is there a different way to achieve this particular CV, i.e. use a pre-defined column for a "Leave-group-out" CV?

Comment: Afaik, "meta" features are used to _tag_ the data instances (such as _user id_, _uuid_, ...), but are unused (and not useful) for learning.